# Qt3D on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt3d

Is it possible to run Qt 3D with pure C++ on android? All C++ examples, like the basic shape C++ example, got this entry in the .pro file:

```
android|ios|tvos|winrt {
warning( "This example is not supported for android, ios, tvos, or winrt." )
}
```

I wrote an app that is very similar to the example but smaller. It's just a Qt3DWindow with one entity and some components. It works on my laptop (Windows 8.1) but it crashes on my AVDs.
I tried some Nexus and Pixel AVDs with APIs ranging from 23 to 25 with software and hardware graphics rendering.

I followed [this](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-android.html) guide to set up QtCreator 2.3.0 and I'm using Qt 5.9.0-X86-rc. All android examples are running fine.

This is the application output:

> I art     : Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>   W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   I QtCore  : Start
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Gui.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x53bd4
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Gui.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Network.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x13595
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Network.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DCore.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0xd8b1
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DCore.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Concurrent.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0xbb2
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Concurrent.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DRender.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x2a36b
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DRender.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Gamepad.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x2f36
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Gamepad.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DInput.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0xadb2
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DInput.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DLogic.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x19c4
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DLogic.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DExtras.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x11617
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt53DExtras.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Widgets.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x6bf99
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libQt5Widgets.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x8747
>   W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   I Qt      : qt start
>   W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x16dd
>   W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/gamepads/libandroidgamepad.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x1223
>   W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/gamepads/libandroidgamepad.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example-2/lib/x86/libandroid_test.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x6f6
>   D OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
>   D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa93bd80, tid 5833
>   D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa93bf80, tid 5854
>   I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>   W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/sceneparsers/libgltfsceneimport.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x3816
>   W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/sceneparsers/libgltfsceneimport.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
>   D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9ed4a8c0, tid 5862
>   D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa305c00, tid 5855
>   F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 5862 (QtThread)
>   "org.qtproject.example" died.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to deploy the app on a physical device. Seems to be an issue with the (configuration of my) AVDs.